# How to select maximum value of two identical columns in same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
     id1  id2  name
1     1    2   a
2     3    4   b
3     5    6   c
4     7    8   d
5     9    10  e

select id1, id2, name
from Emp3
where id2 in (select MAX(id2) from Emp3)
```

How can I print only the  maximum number?

Comment: Maximum of what? Show us the expected result! (I.e. what's wrong with your current query)?

Comment: From your above query, it will result 5th row of your table. Is this what you require?

Comment: From above query i need only maximum value i.e., from the above given values i need only 10 to print on my output screen

Answer (score 0):

USe

```
select id2
from Emp3
where id2 in (select MAX(id2) from Emp3)
```

This will print only 10

if you want the maximum among those 2 columns then use

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(id1) >= MAX(id2) THEN MAX(id1)
        WHEN MAX(id2) >= MAX(id1) THEN MAX(id2)
    END AS MaxValue
FROM Emp3
```

Answer (score 0):

If both id columns are indexed, use derived table with `UNION ALL`:

```
select max(id)
from
(
 select max(id1) as id from Emp3
 union all
 select max(id2) from Emp3
)
```

If they are not indexed, use `CASE`:

```
select max(case when id1 > id2 then id1
                when id2 > id1 then id2
                else coalesce(id1,id2) end)
from Emp3
```

This answer uses `COALESCE` to handle `NULLs` (if there are any...) The table will be read only once. (With the UNION solution the table will be read twice, and you don't want to do that without any index!)

---

Older answers:

I guess you want the row with the highest id1/id2 value?

Return a row when no other row with higher id value exists:

```
select id1, id2, name
from Emp3 e1
where not exists (select 1 from Emp3 e2
                  where e2.id1 > e1.id1
                     or e2.id1 > e1.id2
                     or e2.id2 > e1.id1
                     or e2.id2 > e1.id2)
```

Will return both rows if there's a tie. (Two or more rows with same highest value.)

Alternative solution, use `TOP`, combined with `ORDER BY` with `CASE` to find each rows larger id value:

```
select TOP 1 id1, id2, name
from Emp3
order by case when id1 > id2 then id1 else id2 end desc
```

Alternative 3, a sub-query with `UNION ALL` to find largest id:

```
select TOP 1 id1, id2, name
from Emp3
where (select max(case when id1 > id2 then id1 else id2 end) from Emp3) in (id1,id2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TOP` and `ORDER BY` to get the result

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID2 FROM Emp3 ORDER BY ID2 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(id) from (
    select max(id1) as id from Emp3
    union
    select max(id2) as id from Emp3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID1 INT ,ID2 INT ,NAME VARCHAR(80))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1,2,'NME1')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (3,4,'NME2')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (5,6,'NME3')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (7,8,'NME4')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (9,10,'NME5')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (11,12,'NME6')
SELECT * FROM @T

SELECT MAX(ID1) ID FROM 
(
SELECT ID1 FROM @T T1
UNION 
SELECT ID2 FROM @T T2
)TT
```